# Modify multiprocess function to accept a list of args

Tags: python

How do I update the `multi_proc_parallel_functions` function below to accept a list of args.  This is using the [multiprocess](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/) module.

Please note I will be using this with AWS Lambda and other multiprocessing modules can have issues on Lambda.

`adder` functions below are simply toy functions used to demo the issue.

```
import multiprocess as mp

def parallel_functions(function,send_end):

    send_end.send(function())


def multi_proc_parallel_functions(function_list,target_func):
    jobs = []
    pipe_list = []

    for function in function_list:

        recv_end, send_end = mp.Pipe(False)
        p = mp.Process(target=target_func, args=(function,send_end))

        jobs.append(p)

        pipe_list.append(recv_end)
        p.start()

    result_list = [x.recv() for x in pipe_list]

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()

    return result_list
    

def adder10():
    return np.random.randint(5) + 10

def adder1000():
    return np.random.randint(5) + 1000
```

Create a list of functions

```
function_list = [adder10,adder10,adder10,adder1000]
```

Run all functions

```
multi_proc_parallel_functions(function_list,parallel_functions)

[13, 13, 13, 1003]
```

How do I update the `multi_proc_parallel_functions` to accept a varied length list of args which will vary per function as follows:

```
def adder10(x,y):
    return np.random.randint(5) + 10 + x * y

def adder1000(a,b, c):
    return np.random.randint(5) + 1000 -a + b +c
```

I think this will require *args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one way of doing it (with positional argument support):

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def parallel_functions(function, send_end, *args):
    send_end.send(function(*args))

def multi_proc_parallel_functions(function_list, target_func):
    jobs = []
    pipe_list = []

    for (function, *args) in function_list:
        recv_end, send_end = mp.Pipe(False)
        p = mp.Process(target=target_func, args=(function, send_end, *args))
        jobs.append(p)
        pipe_list.append(recv_end)
        p.start()

    result_list = [x.recv() for x in pipe_list]

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()

    return result_list
```

```
import numpy as np

def adder10(x, y):
    return np.random.randint(5) + 10 + x * y

def adder1000(a, b, c):
    return np.random.randint(5) + 1000 -a + b +c

multi_proc_parallel_functions(
  [ (adder10, 5, 4),
    (adder10, 1, 2),
    (adder1000, 5, 6, 7) ],
  parallel_functions
)
```

Note that how the multiprocessing module works will depend on whether you are on Windows, macOS or Linux.

On Linux, the default way of creating a `mp.Process` is by using the `fork`-syscall, which means the function/its arguments does not need to be serializable/possible to pickle. The child process will inherit memory from the parent. macOS supports `fork`, Windows doesn't.

On Windows/macOS, the `spawn` syscall is used by default instead. This requires that everything sent to the child process is serializable/possible to pickle. This means you won't be able to send lambda expressions or dynamically created functions for example.

Example of something that would work on Linux (with your original implementation), but not on Windows (or macOS by default):

```
multi_proc_parallel_functions(
  [ lambda: adder10(5, 4),
    lambda: adder10(1, 2),
    lambda: adder1000(5, 6, 7) ],
  parallel_functions
)

# spawn: _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x7fce7cc43010>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
# fork: [30, 12, 1008]
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using the `operator` module, which has functions for the math operations. This way, you can send a list of operators and values to modify the initial value in a flexible way.

Example where each argument is a tuple of `(operator, value)`:

```py
import operator

import numpy as np


np.random.seed(123)


def adder(*args):
    x = np.random.randint(5)

    print(x)

    for operator, value in args:
        x = operator(x, value)
        print(x)
   
    return x


adder((operator.add, 5), (operator.mul, 10))
```

This operation (`2 + 5 * 10`) outputs:

```
2
7
70
```

Comment: Hi.  Question is how do I update the `multi_proc_parallel_functions` function to accept a list of args. The question is based on usage of the multiprocess module.